# strictly distribute width equally and dynamically via flex box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How does one enforce equal distribution of width irrespective of the content size inside of it using a flex box?

I have `ul` element which contains three `li` elements that have to be of equal width. Using `flex: 1 0 0` doesn't work correctly as you can see in the demo. The third `li` element takes up all the space.

**UPDATE**
The list is dynamically created and using Javascript to calculate percentages is not what I am looking for.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F00;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>AAAAAAA</li>
<li>BBB</li>
<li>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox can't do that but there is another option.

## CSS Tables

Of course, if the text is too long it will overflow, we can fix that with `word-break:break-all`.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F00;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
li {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>AAAAAAA</li>
  <li>BBB</li>
  <li>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</li>
</ul>


<ul>
  <li>AAAAAAA</li>
  <li>BBB</li>
  <li>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</li>
  <li>DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: technically this isn't using flex, is it?

Comment: True...added comment to that effect.

Comment: Tables for layout take so much heat, yet they always come through.

Comment: Indeed, they're a nice fallback and we don't get the *"tables aren't for layout"* fanatics! :)

Comment: I want to start a movement that unordered lists aren't for navigation. Who's with me?

Comment: Trouble is they're so handy for structuring submenus...That's a little harder to do with non-`ul`

Comment: I can't tell from your response if you knew I was kidding. I was playing on the *tables aren't for layout* extremism.

Comment: No...my giggle radar is off today...Damn!

Comment: ...but I'm fully on board with "*links aren't buttons"* ... **because theyre not!**

Answer (score 2):

Use the `flex-basis` property. (This answer was posted before the question was updated.)

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F00;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
li {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  flex: 1 0 33.33%;              /* adjusted */
  overflow: hidden;              /* new */
  box-sizing: border-box;        /* new */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>AAAAAAA</li>
  <li>BBB</li>
  <li>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Since the list is dynamic, I can not write 33% in flex-basis.

Comment: I agree but I suspect the OP was after a dynamic option...but as we know that's not what Flexbox does.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is quite late to respond. But thought of putting here, as it might help others.

this can be achieved by just adding `width:0` to li (child) elements. please look at my snippet.

reference : http://www.sumnoise.com/2016/04/06/equal-width-flexbox-columns/

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F00;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  flex: 1;
  width: 0; // Fix for having equal widths for all children
  //Below are just to wrap the text overflowing 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>AAAAAAA</li>
<li>BBB</li>
<li>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</li>
</ul>
```